# Alternative for eval to get array object from a string where JSON.parse is not working

Tags: javascript

`window.eval("['bcs/abc/xyz.pdf', 'bcs/abc/xyz.pdf']");`
gives output array object with urls
how to do this without using eval, any elegant solution? Json.parse is not working in this scenario.

Comment: If your array elements would be enclosed in double quotes, then you could use `JSON.parse('["bcs/abc/xyz.pdf", "bcs/abc/xyz.pdf"]')`

Comment: `JSON.parse` is not working because *it's not valid JSON*. The most elegant solution is to make sure whatever is producing that value is producing *valid* JSON. Post-fixing the wrong data is pretty much always the wrong approach.

Comment: this is not JSON encoded string. you directly put an array in `'` quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to fix the server, but if you cannot then

```js
const getArr = str => JSON.parse(
  `{"arr":${
  str.replace(/'/g,'"')
  }}`
)["arr"];
  
const arr = getArr(`['bcs/abc/xyz.pdf', 'bcs/abc/xyz.pdf']`)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse it manually using regex

```
"['bcs/abc/xyz.pdf', 'bcs/abc/xyz.pdf']".replace(/^\[|"|'|\]$/g, '').split(/,\s?/)
```

Here regex used to replace brackets, after which you can split it using comma and zero or multiple white spaces as separator.